# Cannot send email through SMTP in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird, smtp

[image]

I have a school provided email (name@ins.edu) that is located on an outlook server (pod#####.outlook.com) that I configured in Thunderbird using the settings provided by the web-based outlook portal. I am connecting via IMAP and can retrieve all email messages and synchronize all folder except the `Sent` folder as it is tied to SMTP.

I've tried every configuration of the Outgoing Server Settings I could but none work. (SSL/TSL vs STARTTLS with each of the authentication methods)

Oddly, when I was configuring the email in Thunderbird it continued to fail when I specified the settings I got from outlook.com but succeeded in creating the account with incorrect IMAP settings that it detected by polling the server. It wasn't working after completing the set up so I changed the IMAP settings to what they should have been and now as I mentioned, I am able to retrieve mail.

This has never been a problem before and I have used several Outlook/Thunderbird clients as well as android mail clients without many problems. I can send mail on my phone and in Outlook.

**Update:** I was able to send a test message a few times but it still could not copy the message to the Sent folder. I also seem to have 3 Sent folders (2 "Sent" and 1 "Sent Items"). I was able to view one Sent folder's contents so I thought that one worked but after setting the outgoing mail to copy the message to the supposedly working Sent folder, I am now no longer able to view the contents. Whats going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a great deal of "folder corruption" via duplicates and improperly set up folders that were being referenced incorrectly. Had to restart about 10 times and continually re-connect to the server while cleaning up the duplicates/wrong folders that were added via K9-Mail on my Android phone and perhaps Thunderbird as well.

Moral: keep a clean and tidy folder set up for email.